# How I can set the errors in spanish language on postfix server email?

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I have a postfix servers in my network and very much users not read the english lenguage, and I want set the errors in spanish language.

My version of postfix email servers is:

```
mail_version = 2.9.6
```

My OS:

```
On Ubuntu 12.04 server LTS
```

Thanks in advances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set custom error messages overriding the default English ones with:

```
bounce_template_file = /etc/postfix/bounce.cf
```

From the [manual](http://www.postfix.org/bounce.5.html):

> ```
>    The  Postfix  bounce(8)  server  produces  delivery status notification
>    (DSN) messages for undeliverable mail, delayed mail, successful  deliv-
>    ery or address verification requests.
>
>    By  default,  these notifications are generated from built-in templates
>    with message headers and message text. Sites can override the  built-in
>    information  by  specifying a bounce template file with the bounce_tem-
>    plate_file configuration parameter.
> ```